# Cannot open Jenkins from Fedora 22 Host, using Puppet Learning VM

Tags: service, jenkins, continuous-integration, puppet

After successful installation of Jenkins, using instructions from https://forge.puppetlabs.com/rtyler/jenkins , now I am stuck on getting jenkins gui from actually showing up in host OS ( Fedora 22 ).

VBoxed Network adapter has bridged connection.

I have tried:

- setting up port 8081 ;
- setting up firewall opening with parameter 'configure_firewall' to
  true ..
- inspecting Chrome data and changing various URL parts like protocols, etc.

When I try to access jenkins instance from Chrome 43, all I get is this:

```
No data received

ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
```

Afaik jenkins should be available once its service is started in VBoxed CentOS, but seems like there is something more tricky. What am I missing?

Comment: First check if Jenkins is working: `ps aux | grep jenkins`, next check on which port Jenkins is listening: `netstat -a | grep LISTEN`. Maybe it is listening on completely different port.

Comment: I get something like this: | root | 4331 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 7749 | 736 | pts/0 | S+ | 10:44 | 0:00 | grep jenkins | . Seems like jenkins does not run even if service starts up correctly. Obviously, no process is listening to port either :(

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using the learning VM for sandbox puppet work. It's been specially customised to run the Learning VM tasks.

I'd use a standard Fedora Vagrant box avaliable somewhere like here:
https://getfedora.org/en/cloud/download/index.html

Comment: Hmm. Vagrant box... Well, I was hoping to get qemu / vbox compatible ISO files ... do not want to mess up my home PC too much with custom packages ... recent upgrade from fc21 to fc22 wen wayyyy to long just because I keep some additional kernel packages and virtualization assets ... :(